# saving e.graphics into a pdf problems

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

i did some e.graphics.draw string/image/line, and i managed to print it using print dialog print document and print previw dialog.  but i wanted to save it into a pdf using microsoft print to pdf. into a specific folder. without using the file dialog, just one button to save it as pdf.

i dont have an idea what is the next step. so any help is appreciated, btw i searched for more than 10 days, but i couldn't find a way to do this. btw i used itextsharp,and pdf printer. but i couldn't do what i want because i want to save what i did using e.graphics,thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to use the `Graphics` class for drawing, you have to be able to create an instance for the canvas you want to draw on. Can you do that for a PDF using iTextSharp? I don't know as I've never used it but I don't think I've ever seen it done. I think iTextSharp has its own methods for inserting text, images, etc.

The first thing you need to do is determine whether iTextSharp does/can expose a `Graphics` instance. If it does not then you can either give up this idea and use the functionality that iTextSharp does provide, or you can use a `Graphics` object to draw on an `Image` and then insert that into your PDF using whatever functionality iTextSharp provides for that.

Assuming you're going ahead, the first thing you should do is write a method that takes a `Graphics` object as an argument and uses it to draw, e.g.

```cs
private void Draw(Graphics g)
{
    // Call g.DrawString, etc, here.
}
```

You can then call that method anywhere you have a `Graphics` object to perform that same drawing. If you are currently using `e.Graphics` to draw in the `PrintPage` event handler of a `PrintDocument`, you would move that code to the method above and change `e.Graphics` to `g`, then call the method and pass `e.Graphics` instead. You can then call the same method elsewhere with different `Graphics` objects, e.g. create a `Bitmap` of the desired dimensions, call `Graphics.FromImage` and then pass the result to that method to do the same drawing on that `Bitmap`.

Comment: i already drew my stuff, the problem is that i wanna set a button inwhich i can save these into pdf instead of opening print preview and select the microsoft printer then choose the directory!

Comment: And I've explained how you can do that. Follow the instructions provided.